# Modifying the suitebar in 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, 2016, suitebar, suite-links

I've been making a few DOM modifications to the SuiteBar in 2016 using javascript/jquery and I've noticed that sometimes on first load the changes don't take at all or only some do. To fix it, reloading the page solves the problem.

I think our main issue is that we aren't using master pages but Control delegates instead and for some reason I haven't be able to force this script to load at the end of the page instead so I'm facing a timing issue on first load, likely cause the file isn't in the cache by then.

I'm trying to find a more consistent approach. This is what I'm doing:

```
$(function () {
    // Wait for resources, then do stuff
    SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['init.js', 'sp.core.js', 'sp.runtime.js', 'sp.js'], function () {
        // Prepare page
        var siteTitle = $('a.o365cs-nav-appTitle > span.o365cs-nav-brandingText');
        siteTitle
            .empty()
            .text(title)
            .closest('a').attr({
                'href': myobject.currentPath(),
                'title': myobject.returnHomeTitle
            });

    // Replace site logo and set link to home
    $("img.ms-siteicon-img")
        .attr({
            "src": myobject.siteLogo,
        })
        .closest('a')
        .attr('href', myobject.currentPath());
    });
})
```

Comment: Have you thought of injecting the code in the pagelayout?

Comment: @AhmedMahmoud what do you mean, editing the master page?

Comment: I was thinking that you can create a page layout and inject this code inside it, then create your pages off that page layout!

Answer (score -1):

With the Release of the SharePoint 2016, Microsoft Introduced new PowerShell cmdlets which will set these things in a couple of lines.

If you are ok with PowerShell, you can follow below approach.

1. To change Suite Navigation Branding Text

> $webapp = Get-SPWebApplication “http://ca.krossfarm.com”
>       $webapp.SuiteNavBrandingText = “Central Admin (Dev)”
>       $webapp.Update()

2. To Set the Logo

> $webapp.SuiteNavBrandingLogoUrl ="http://ca.krossfarm.com1/Shared%20Documents/leaf-and-flames-logo.jpg"
>
> $webapp.SuiteNavBrandingLogoTitle ="KrossFarm"
>   $webapp.SuiteNavBrandingLogoNavigationUrl = "http://ca.krossfarm.com"
>
> $webapp.Update()

MSDN Ref [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34202.sharepoint-2016-how-to-change-suitbars-text-powershell.aspx)